# Watching for files on remote shared folder using tWaitForFile

Tags: talend

I am trying tWaitForFile component in Talend to watch for new created files. It seems to be working for local directory (I am using Windows 7).

However, when I point it to a shared folder like `//ps1.remotemachine.com/Continents/Africa` it doesn't work. It doesn't give me file creation signals like it gives for local directory.

Am I missing something?

**Update:**

In my testing so far, below are the observations for *monitoring files on network path*:

1. Talend tWaitForFile - Inconsistent results. Only gives notification sometimes. Majority of time, doesn't.
2. Java Nio WatchService - Tried this out of Talend solution. It does give notification for created files on network path. However, when the number of folders to be monitored on network path are too many, it starts missing events of some of the folders. In my case, it was around 100 folders to be monitored.

Hence, aborted both of above approaches and sticking on scheduler based running of Talend jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`"\\\\ps1.remotemachine.com/Continents/Africa"`

[image]

If you use the value from a context then you don't need to double "\"

[image]

And in the tWaitForFile

[image]

Comment: I have tried with "\\\\" and "//" and also by putting the path in context variable with "\\". It is not working for me.

Comment: Maybe access right to list the content on the share ?

Comment: I tried a java program using java.nio WatchService to watch for remote directory changes. By using that, I am getting the events for file creation on remote shared path. It is on the same setup and permissions. So, if tWaitForFile is using java.nio behind the scenes, then even it should have got the events, which unfortunately isn't happening.

Comment: By looking at the generated code,  tWaitForFile is simply doing  a file.listFiles(new java.io.FilenameFilter() { ... } . Are you watching for a specific extension or any new file ?